# route terminal server client over ssh

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, rdp

I want to access a virtualbox guest from Lubuntu thrue "terminal server client" (rdp on 3389) How can I route (from Lubuntu) my "terminal server client" over a ssh connection I establish before to a firewall (not on same lan)? ssh forewarding is active on the firewall.

Thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 1):

To open an ssh tunnel between your Lubuntu machine and the virtualbox machine, you will want to run something like

```
ssh -f user@firewall.fqdn -L 3389:firewall.fqdn:3389 -N
```

Then you point your rdp client on Lubuntu to localhost:3389. This will push all the traffic on localhost:3389 through the ssh tunnel to the virtualbox machine's port 3389.